# Removing or Restricting Access to Page Templates for Editor Role

Tags: page-template, user-roles, page-attributes

I have a question about restricting access to page templates for blog editors who may create new pages in the future. During my buildout, I had to create specific templates to add custom features for specific pages (i.e. FAQs pulls from a CPT in a separate loop, but allows the editor to add an intro paragraph using the standard "page" post type)

Now as I hand off the site, I want to make sure that those templates aren't re-used by the site editors as they are constructing new pages. Is there a way to limit the available page templates by user role? Or is it possible to just remove the "Page Template" dropdown completely? I can use Adminimize (http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/) to remove the dropdown, but the label still remains.

Thanks,
Devin

Comment: Good question, **but**: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to remove that [metabox](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) from the edit page - this solution also assumes that the editors don't have access to edit themes.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'restrict_access' );
function restrict_access() {
if(!current_user_can('edit_themes')){
    remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'page','normal' );
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think [`remove_post_type_support`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support) can be used for the scope:

```
add_action('load-post.php', 'no_page_templates');
add_action('load-post-new.php', 'no_page_templates');

function read_only_content() {
  if ( ! current_user_can('manage_options') ) { // change the cap with the wanted one
    $scr = get_current_screen();
    remove_post_type_support( $scr->post_type, 'page-attributes' );
  }
}
```